# PHP still won't allow file uploads larger than 2 MB

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-ec2

I have a Debian Squeeze install on an Amazon EC2 instance running Apache2, and PHP 5.3.3-7. I would like it to be able to accept uploads from a standard point-and-shoot camera (about 5 MB). Accordingly, I've edited php.ini in /etc/php5/apache2/ to allow for up to 18MB uploads, and I've upped the time PHP will allow to work on a script.

Despite restarting Apache and even the machine itself, it absolutely refuses to upload any file larger than 2 MB. Is this an EC2 problem or is it still a PHP issue. I'm fairly sure I've ironed out all possibility of it being PHP, but I've been staring at the same 4 lines of code for the last week and searching like a mad person for what this could possibly be.

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 120
...
max_input_time = 120
...
upload_max_filesize = 18M
...
post_max_size = 18M
```

I have double checked just now with phpinfo(), these settings are in effect, but it still does not work.

Comment: Please share with us the lines you edited in `php.ini` and the PHP srcript. Also check your `phpinfo()` to make sure your configs are properly set.

Answer (score 5):

Check settings `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file

Comment: I've updated my posting to show the lines of php.ini that I have modified from their defaults. But as I said in the description, editing these, and reloading the server (and even restarting the machine) has not worked.

Comment: What's print `phpinfo()` function? In output of this function you could see which `php.ini` file is uses, may be this is not `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely to be Sohusin. The default packages from APT on debian has Sohusin built in.

This also affects your upload size limit. Take a look at this link for a fix and an explanation:
 http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: I've checked suhosin in phpinfo and it says that it's limit is set to 0, but I can upload smaller files. Just not larger ones. In any case, every line of all suhosin.ini files I find in /etc/php5/ are commented out, so any changes I make don't impact anything. Is there a different suhosin config file I should be looking for?

Comment: Could you link to your phpinfo?

Answer (score 1):

don't know if that will be of any help on your setup?

**In Apache:**

**TimeOut**

Amount of time the server will wait for certain events before failing a request

**LimitRequestBody**

Restricts the total size of the HTTP request body sent from the client

Also on some server setups you cant change php.inp via scipts

Comment: Yes, I've already edited those 3 lines in my php.ini.

Where in the Apache settings do I edit those other two?

Comment: They are core directives that you should not need to alter unless you have already. They should be adequate, im thinking the problem is someplace else. Have you checked the limit on the file input?

Comment: Ok i see you have direct access to your server files. Those settings look right. Do you get any message after uploading?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the bug (it was in my own script). But, I'm too new of a user to delete/answer my own post right now.

Comment: No problems, always best to check your own scripts first:)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```

Save then run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```