# Why can I not upload files greater than 2MB? Php.ini has already been edited

Tags: php, wamp

I'm having the same problem this guy says he had: [PHP still won't allow file uploads larger than 2 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426698/php-still-wont-allow-file-uploads-larger-than-2-mb), although apparently he solved it.

I, however, cannot find a solution. I've edited the php.ini file to the following values:

`upload_max_filesize = 20M`
`post_max_size = 20M`

I've even tried raising them to 200M, but it still limits it at 2M, according to `phpinfo()`.

Here are some of the variables per php.ini (name, local value, master value):

`file_uploads   On  On`

`max_file_uploads   20  20`

`upload_max_filesize    2M  2M`

I've restarted everything. The original value when I checked php.ini for upload_max_filesize was 10M anyway. It will upload smaller files, just nothing above 2MB.

Comment: Maybe your HTML files has attiribute of `MAX_FILE_SIZE` set to `2MB`

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the correct php.ini file?

Comment: This is my html: `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">` I'm sure it has to do with php because phpinfo() is saying it's 2M, despite what php.ini says.

Comment: @flogvit I do not know how to be sure. I'm running WAMP and there's only one php.ini file. I'll look around some to see.

Comment: @flogvit Yes, you are correct. You have found the problem. How do I change what php file it's using? I'm going to do some digging around in the time being.

Answer (score 3):

- Assicure that you have saved your php.ini.
- Restart your webserver for example the service of Apache2 if you use it
- Print again a page with phpinfo() and assicure that value has changed if not you haven't wrong file to edit.
- Assure that html has attribute MAX_FILE_SIZE

Another way is to change in PHP this setting like:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible the file size limit is being overwritten in an .htaccess file, or in your PHP application, through ini_set() calls.

I will also remind you that when you change those values in php.ini, you probably need to restart Apache.

If this isn't something your webhost will let you do, you could always use ini_set() calls yourself, in your script.  For example, place this near the top of your script:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

Comment: ini_set() is not changing anything, however, I have found a solution.

Comment: Once you have moved past your issue, please post your solution so others may benefit if they have similar problems in the future.  Thanks, Richard.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before. If you are running certain versions of web servers, such as running `php-fpm` with `nginx`, your `php.ini` file won't be in the place you expect it. For example, I believe `php-fpm` doesn't follow the normal `php.ini`, but rather a `www.conf` located in it's `conf.d` directory.

Anyway, check and make sure that your configuration isn't being overridden by a separate `php.ini` or other config file. If you cannot fix it in this way, you may have luck doing what Richard and Alessandro suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. the setting `post_max_size` was set to `3M`.

I fixed it in the `php.ini` file from the `/wamp/apache/bin` folder.

I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Always ensure that it is the correct php.ini file that you are updating its values.
I spent 2 weeks reconfiguring IIS7 only to realize that there were 2 php.ini files on was in the C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4 and the other was in C:\php... however the one that worked was: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4

To ensure that you are on the correct path to the php.ini file

- create a phpinfo.php file (structure of file below)

  phpinfo();
- call the file in the browser like: `http://servername/websitename/phpinfo.php`
- Check the lline shown in pic below to verify that you are indeed editing the correct php.ini file.
- [image: List item]

Hope this helps cause it helped me. PS. Don't forget to make the changes mentioned above to increase the upload size limit

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem  and also I did the same changes in the **ini.php** file

> upload_max_filesize = 200M 
>   post_max_size = 200M

But it doesn't solve my problem. So, I went to wamp server in the taskbar ([where we can see the green 'W' sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa0E2.png)) and left clicked on it

> PHP > PHP SETTINGS > upload_max_filesize = 256M (as the changes i made in ini.php were actually not made).

Then it WORKED.

Answer (score 0):

Flogvit pretty much answered my question. WAMP was using a different php.ini file than was listed in the WAMP PHP settings option. I looked at the wamp configuration file and it was just "php.ini." I changed it to the full path of the php.ini file I wanted to use (there was another in the IIS folder), I restarted it and nothing happened. However, after restarting the computer, it now works. For some reason `ini_set()` doesn't work, however the solution is this:

1) open wampmanager.conf

2) change "phpConfFile = " from php.ini to the full path of the php.ini file you'd like to use, putting it in double quotes.

3) restart the computer that WAMP is on.

Thanks again for the help. That was a pretty weird problem and I don't know why I couldn't just restart WAMP (which runs all the servers, including the Apache server). I'm guessing there was something running outside of WAMP that was being run by WAMP, which is a bit of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are editing the wrong config file. Check where your config file is being loaded from and edit that one instead. You might be editing the one located at /etc/php/[version]/cli/php.ini.

In my case, my loaded config file is at /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini

[image: phpinfo]